# HighCharts Line Chart not rendering completely when parent web page is printed

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, web-applications, responsive-design

I have encountered an issue with the HighCharts Line Chart when attempting to print the parent web page that contains the chart. The web application, built using Angular, integrates a custom web component responsible for rendering the line chart. While the chart is responsive and displays correctly within the web application, it fails to behave the same way when printed.

1. The parent web page consists of a report with a print button and three cards. The middle card contains the line chart.
2. The chart's responsiveness does not carry over to the printed version. Specifically, the x-axis is partially hidden on the right side of the printed page.
3. The print button triggers the standard window.print() function to open the print dialog in Chrome.
4. The report is designed to support various page sizes, such as A4, A3, A2, letter, etc.

[Screenshot - X-axis arrow is hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPXnh.png)

I have attempted several approaches to address this issue, but none of them have provided a satisfactory solution:

1. Utilizing page size change events in the print dialog and listening for real-time width changes did not work, as the print dialog does not emit any events related to page size changes.
2. Implementing a resize event listener also proved ineffective in resolving the problem.
3. Trying to use media match for detecting page size changes was not successful, as the print dialog does not emit any relevant events or information regarding page size changes.
4. Applying CSS properties directly on the chart's SVG helped with responsiveness, but it resulted in extra margin appearing at the top and bottom of the chart. The extra margin seemed to be caused by the chart being rendered again, but window.print() captured the pre-rendered view, leading to this unexpected behavior.
5. Attempting to set the chart's width to '100%' instead of null caused the chart to break and only rendered the y-axis.

I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this bug and make the HighCharts Line Chart fully responsive when the parent web page is printed. It is essential to ensure that the chart adapts correctly to various page sizes (A4, A3, A2, letter, etc.) while maintaining its proper appearance in the print preview.

Any insights or suggestions to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, are you able to reproduce this issue in the online editor? You can start here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I will try to reproduce it on Stackblitz.